# Weird Script sometimes work and some time it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a script to retrieve data on scroll

**Really weird**, some times it works good and some times it doesn't work
I also to make "alert" it is still not working
and when put the alert in a clean script in the same page it works normal 
can you help ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        alert('zzz');
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            alert("zzz");
            var loaded_ads = 0;
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 100) {
                var num_ads = <?php echo $num_ads ;?>;

                loaded_ads += 10;
                $.get("e3lanat/get_ads/" + loaded_ads, function (data) {
                    $("#Ebda2").append(data);
                });

                if (loaded_ads >= num_ads - 10)
                {
                }


            }
        });



    </script>
```

Comment: Try wrapping that whole function in a $(document).ready(function(){ /* all that code */ });

Comment: still not working @DataHerder

Comment: Open this page in chrome and then open "Chrome Developer Tools", refresh the page with this developer window open and watch for any errors

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap the your jQuery codes with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your codes here
});
```

Explanation: with the ready block wrapped, your jQuery code will be executed AFTER jQuery JS is loaded.

Comment: "not working" is not a valid issue description. Please explain your issue. What is shown in Developer Console?

Comment: get method is not working
and it didn't show in the console, I also put an alert to be sure that it is working on ready 
and it didn't show up

Comment: Look at the "Network" tab. Is everything loaded up properly (and finished loading) ?

Comment: all finish loading but I can't see jquery-1.8.3.min.js in the list

Comment: It's impossible. Everything included in the page will be loaded in theory. Try to reload when the Developer Console is open (make sure Cache is disabled)